# Where do you get the tool they use at the Genius Bar to remove SIM cards?

Tags: iphone, sim, apple-store

I was at the Genius Bar recently and the techs had a tiny tool on their loop of cables that looked like a pin with an oval-shaped loop at the top. Anyone know where to acquire this tool?

I know I could cut and bend a small paper clip, but this looked a bit thinner and sturdier. They used it to pop out the SIM card and clean out the Lightning port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you purchase an international or unlocked iPhone, it comes with this SIM ejection tool. They cannot be purchased from Apple, however they are sold on eBay/Amazon/etc.

Comment: Thanks! Mine is a subsidized phone, but with your tip I found some on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

The "Apple SIM ejector" is a glorified paperclip. A much better (and more comfortable) tool is a 0.8mm hex driver. Find the precision tools section of your local hardware store and get one that fits. Do NOT get a pointy-end driver like Phillips. Hex drivers have flat ends and smooth sides.

And don't use metal objects to clean out the connector - a toothpick won't scratch up the electrical connections.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a toothpick, but it only got in a few millimeters before it was too thick. Maybe a flat one would be better.